# Display Condicional no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho um código de despesas, quero que um formulário de input chamado "numeroKm" com display:none apareça somente se no campo de despesas, estiver selecionado "Quilometragem". Retirei do código pra ficar mais sintetizado as opções do select.

```
<select name="tipoDespesa" required style="margin-left:50px;">
  \*várias opções aqui*\
</select>

<input type="number" name="numeroKm" placeholder="KM" id="km" step=".1" style="display: none; height: 30px;width: 70;padding-left: 10px;">
<input type="number" name="precoDespesa" placeholder="R$" id="valor" step=".01" required placeholder="Insira um valor!">

<script>
  let ehQuilometragem = document.getElementsByName("tipoDespesa")[0]
  if (ehQuilometragem == "Quilometragem"){
    function adicionaCampoKm(){
      $("#km").Show();
    }
  adicionaCampoKm()
};
</script>
```

Tentei esse script ao fim mas aparentemente não obtive resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc está misturando **jQuery** com **Javascript(Vanilla)** sem necessidade, isto é bem simples de se fazer, segue um exemplo que fiz com **if/else**, mas, na verdade daria pra deixar em uma linha só utilizando condição ternária:

```js
$(() => {
  let select = $('[name=tipoDespesa]');
  let inptKm = $('#km');
  
  select.on('change', () => {
    if(select.val() == 'Quilometragem') inptKm.show()
    else inptKm.hide()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="tipoDespesa" required style="margin-left:50px;">
  <option value="coisa">Uma coisa</option>
  <option value="outra">Outra coisa</option>
  <option value="Quilometragem">Quilometragem</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="numeroKm" placeholder="KM" id="km" step=".1" style="display: none; height: 30px;width: 70;padding-left: 10px;">
<input type="number" name="precoDespesa" placeholder="R$" id="valor" step=".01" required placeholder="Insira um valor!">
```

Só um exemplo utilizando ternário:

```js
$(() => {
  let select = $('[name=tipoDespesa]');
  let inptKm = $('#km');

  select.on('change', () => {
    select.val() == 'Quilometragem' ? inptKm.show() : inptKm.hide()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="tipoDespesa" required style="margin-left:50px;">
  <option value="coisa">Uma coisa</option>
  <option value="outra">Outra coisa</option>
  <option value="Quilometragem">Quilometragem</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="numeroKm" placeholder="KM" id="km" step=".1" style="display: none; height: 30px;width: 70;padding-left: 10px;">
<input type="number" name="precoDespesa" placeholder="R$" id="valor" step=".01" required placeholder="Insira um valor!">
```